# Proving Order Statistics Are Independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on the following problem: Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be independent random variables with a common continuous distribution function.

Let $T^{(n)}(\omega) = (T_1^{(n)}(\omega),..., T_n^{(n)}(\omega))$ be the permutation $(t_1,..., t_n)$ of $(1,..., n)$ for which 
$X_{t_1}(\omega) < X_{t_2}(\omega) < \cdots X_{t_n}(\omega)$. Let $Y_n$ be the rank of $X_n$ $(Y_n = r$ if and only if there exactly $r - 1$ values of $i$ for which $X_i < X_n).$

An exercise in my textbook (Billingsley, Exercise 20.8) then claims that $Y_1, Y_2,...$ are independent. This doesn't seem like it should be true, since $Y_1$ seems to carry information about $Y_2$. How could I prove this fact?

Comment: Changing the title to something like '...ranks of order statistics are independent' would be more fitting I think. Because order statistics themselves are never independent.

Answer (score 2):

No. $Y_1$ does not carry information about $Y_2$. Indeed, for $i=1,2$, let $N$ be the number of observations, among $X_1,\dots,X_i$, strictly less than $X_i$. Hence 
$$
P(Y_1=1)=P(N=0)=1.
$$
On the other hand
$$
P(Y_2=1)=P(N=0)=P(X_1\geq X_2)=\frac{1}{2}=P(X_1<X_2)=P(N=1)=P(Y_2=2).
$$
Consequently,
$$
P(Y_1=1,Y_2=1)=P(Y_2=1)=P(Y_1=1)P(Y_2=1)
$$
and
$$
P(Y_1=1,Y_2=2)=P(Y_2=2)=P(Y_1=1)P(Y_2=2).
$$
Therefore, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you understand the definition of $Y_n$ correctly. It is the rank of $X_n$ among $X_1, \ldots, X_n$: $Y_n = r$ if and only if $X_i < X_n$ for exactly $r-1$ values of $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

(For example, $Y_4$ is the rank of $X_4$ among $X_1, \ldots, X_4$, while $Y_{6}$ is the rank of $X_6$ among $X_1, \ldots, X_6$.)

As a sanity check, I show $P(Y_2 = 1, Y_4 = 3) = P(Y_2 = 1) P(Y_4 = 3)$ below, and leave the general case (how does one prove independence of $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$?) to you.

$$P(Y_2 = 1, Y_4 = 3) = P(T^{(4)} \in \{(2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 4, 1), (3, 2, 4, 1)\}) = \frac{3}{4!} = \frac{1}{8},$$
$$P(Y_2 = 1) P(Y_4=3) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8}.$$